# 「でしょう、」 mid-sentence

Tags: grammar

> ちょうどそこに誕生寺という寺がありました。日蓮の生れた村だから誕生寺とでも名を付けたものでしょう、立派な伽藍でした。

How do you parse the second sentence? I asked [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21601/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86-mid-sentence) a while back, but I think it might be different this time.

I think it says "Right over there, there was a temple called the birth temple. They probably called it that because Nichiren was born in this village, and it's an elegant temple."

Or does the "deshou" clause actually modify 伽藍? Maybe it's like "It's an elegant temple that they probably named that way because Nichiren was born in this village."

Also what does もの refer to?

Comment: Sorry to hijack the question, but could the answer also include an explanation of でも in 誕生寺とでも名を付けた? Thanks.

Comment: @user3856370 This でも is [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21519/5010). It implies they could have named it in other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely split the sentence between でしょう and 立派. でしょう does not modify anything that follows. This is similar to your previous question.

(だろう/でしょう sometimes appear as the first half of a compound sentence and works as the reason of the last half. 「雨が降っていたのでしょう、地面が濡れています。」「急いでいたのだろう、息が切れている。」 But the two clauses look independent in your sentence in question.)

I think this もの is a big topic, but basically this もの works as a literary version of explanatory-の to denote a reason. For example you can say 「彼はパーティーに来なかった。私に会いたくなかったものだろう。」